# Improving android Fragment animation performance

Tags: android-fragments, animation

I have an activity with a create account button. On clicking that button it performs a slide up animation. It is slow and choppy. I have tested this on the nexus 4 emulator, as well as a Galaxy s7 edge. I've tried running it in `asynctask` however it did not improve the animation.

Is there a way I can improve animation performance?

Create Account button onclick method:

```
public void createAccount(View v) {
    Log.i("Login", "Create Account button tapped.");

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, 0);
            transaction.add(R.id.create_account_frame_layout, new CreateAccountFragment()).commit();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

CreateAccountFragment class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class CreateAccountFragment extends Fragment {

    public CreateAccountFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_account_background, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem wasn't with the animation. The reason for the poor animation performance was because I only provided one image for the background of all my applications.

Because of this, the image was resizing- an expensive process.

I corrected the issue by providing multiple background images, resized for each dpi in the mipmap folders.